# Photoshop Color Picker Gradient

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to improve my Color Picker code.  It works like Photoshop and I don't want to use a library.

```
    for(var yColor = 0; yColor < 255; yColor++)
    {
        var r = 255,
            g = 0,
            b = 0;
        for(var xColor = 0; xColor < 255; xColor++)
        {
            if(r == 255 && g < 255 && b == 0) g += 6;
            else if(r > 0 && g == 255 && b == 0) r -= 6;
            else if(r == 0 && g == 255 && b < 255) b += 6;
            else if(r == 0 && g > 0 && b == 255) g -= 6;
            else if(r < 255 && g == 0 && b == 255) r += 6;
            else if(r == 255 && g == 0 && b > 0) b -= 6;

            if(r > 255) r = 255;
            else if(r < 0) r = 0;
            else if(g > 255) g = 255;
            else if(g < 0) g = 0;
            else if(b > 255) b = 255;
            else if(b < 0) b = 0;

            var rG = r + yColor > 255 ? 255 : r + yColor;
            var gG = g + yColor > 255 ? 255 : g + yColor;
            var bG = b + yColor > 255 ? 255 : b + yColor;

            GAContext.beginPath();
            GAContext.fillStyle = "rgb(" + rG + ", " + gG + ", " + bG + ")";
            GAContext.rect(xColor, yColor, 1, 1);
            GAContext.fill();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just improve my code.

Comment: If I redraw it, It become a bit laggy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you check the bounds of `r`, `g`, `b` is a bit repetitive:

> ```
> if(r > 255) r = 255;
> else if(r < 0) r = 0;
> else if(g > 255) g = 255;
> else if(g < 0) g = 0;
> else if(b > 255) b = 255;
> else if(b < 0) b = 0;
> ```

You could use a helper function to simplify a bit:

```
function ensureBounds(x) {
    return Math.min(255, Math.max(0, x));  // Thanks @flambino!
}

r = ensureBounds(r);
g = ensureBounds(g);
b = ensureBounds(b);
```

And you could reuse it later to simplify setting `rG`, and the other:

```
var rG = ensureBounds(r + yColor);
var gG = ensureBounds(g + yColor);
var bG = ensureBounds(b + yColor);
```

**UPDATE**

This was my earlier version of the `ensureBounds` function, before I adopted [@flambino](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/14370/flambino)'s suggestion above:

```
function ensureBounds(x) {
    if (x > 255) return 255;
    if (x < 0) return 0;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> If I redraw it, It become a bit laggy.

In my tests, using `createImageData` and `putImageData` to fill the individual pixels ran about 3x faster than `rect` and `fill`.

You can replace this code:

```
GAContext.beginPath();
GAContext.fillStyle = "rgb(" + rG + ", " + gG + ", " + bG + ")";
GAContext.rect(xColor, yColor, 1, 1);
GAContext.fill();
```

With this:

```
pixelData[0] = rG;
pixelData[1] = gG;
pixelData[2] = bG;
GAContext.putImageData(pixel, xColor, yColor);
```

And before the loop, add this:

```
var pixel = GAContext.createImageData(1, 1);
var pixelData = pixel.data;
pixelData[3] = 255;
```

Test it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6rLD5/1/). This Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899799/whats-the-best-way-to-set-a-single-pixel-in-an-html5-canvas) is relevant. You may also be able to figure out a clever way to do this with gradients that would be much faster.